# Trying to center align button in td

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngtable

I'm having trouble centering a button in a td.

This is probably a simple CSS issue, but the app is using bootstrap, AngularJS, AngularJS-ui-bootstrap, and ngTable.  I've included all of these components in my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ks6xTfJxXEQnmVmtJd3M).

I'm trying to set "horizontal-align: middle" on the td with the button, but that doesn't seem to get applied.  The button still leans to the left side of the cell.

Comment: Have you tried adding align="center" on the TD?"

Comment: what about `text-align:center`?

Comment: Did anyone but @dawuut notice that I already had this?  I would have thought I have a problem with the "specificity" of that css rule, but dawuut's solution, which just changes the css rule where I had the "horizontal-align" and "text-align" settings, does actually work.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use :

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

[Here is your updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZheigbuP5z6Fphp1LZAY?p=preview)

Comment: It figures that the correct solution is the least understandable.

Comment: css got its own mysteries :)

Answer (score 16):

As I said in my comment above simply change the TD to have the align="center" property.

```
<td align="center"></td>
```

Since posting this I've discovered that this is deprecated in HTML5 so best just to use "text-align: center" on the TD in your CSS>

Comment: The align attribute was removed in HTML5.

Comment: @null - You learn a new thing everyday! It does still work but best to use CSS instead then I guess.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

`<td style="text-align: center">`

Answer (score 3):

I found that I had to combine the following attributes to center JSF controls on a page:

```
<h:form style="display: block; text-align: center; margin: auto; width: 200px">
<!-- components here -->
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 add these classes to the `<td>` element (mine has 2 buttons):

```
<td class="text-center align-middle">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">-</button>
    </div>                
</td>
```

`text-center` will center content horizontally, while `align-middle` centers content vertically.

Answer (score 2):

It worked fine for me

```
<td align="center">
 <input type="button" style="float:none!important;display:inline;" value="click" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter the button instead of td? Make less impact on the style.

```
table .btn{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
    <td class="table-row-radio-button"> <input type="radio"> </td>
CSS:
    .table-row-radio-button {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

worked for me.